# User input function not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-input

In my Node.js program, I have 2 user input functions. For some reason, it skips all the way down to the 2nd one and executes that, and then finishes. It doesn't even execute the first user input function. I'm not sure why this is and I have been trying to figure it out, but I'm not getting anything. I would really appreciate any feedback you guys might have! I attached a gist of my code. Thanks guys!

```js
var user_answer;
var user_answer2;
const readline = require("readline"); // For user-input
const user_input = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const url = //insert url 
  const headers = {
    //insert headers
  }
const body = {
  //insert body info
}

fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: body
  })
  .then((res) => {
    return res.json()
  })
  .then((json) => {
    user_input.question("Asking question here: ", function(user_answer) { //1ST USER INPUT FUNCTION 
      for ( /* insert for-loop conditions here */ ) {
        //insert code to print stuff out during for-loop

      }
      user_input.close();
    });
  });
  
user_input.question("How are you? ", function(user_answer2) { //2ND USER INPUT FUNCTION 
  if (user_answer2 == 0) {
    console.log('hi');
    user_input.close();
  }
});

user_input.on("close", function() {
  process.exit(0);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first question occurs asynchronously so will occur after the second question that operates synchronously - unfortunately, the first question never get's a chance because the seond question shuts everything down before it has a chance.

You can solve your dilemma and make your code more readable using Async/Await as shown below.

Now the questions will fire in the order you desire.

If you want both questions to fire, don't call `process.exit(0)` when the close button is clicked on the first one.

```js
(async() => {
  const resp = await fetch(...);
  const json = await resp.json();
  user_input.question("Asking question here: ", function(user_answer) {}  );
  user_input.question("How are you? ", function(user_answer2) {});
  user_input.on("close", function() {
    process.exit(0);
  });
})();
```

Comment: Hey @RandyCasburn , thanks for your suggestion! I had a follow-up question though, if that's okay. When doing '(async() => {..........}();', I get an error for the '(async()' part, and it says 'TypeError: {(intermediate value)} is not a function'. Do you know why this could be? I really appreciate your help though, thank you so much!

Comment: If that is your code, you are missing a `)` at the end. The pattern is `( ()=>{} )();` or `( ()=> () );` - either way works.

Comment: I did it how you layed it out in your comment and I still get that error for some reason (I double checked the brackets and paraentheses, seems to be all paired!) Thank you though.

Comment: Make sure you're not missing any semi-colons at the end of your statements. That is common as well.